# how to change slice to loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

how to change slicing to looping?

i will make connect the words game, i must take the connected character in **first_word** and **second_world**

in example: ***ut**ara* can connect by **ut** on *instit**ut***

my lecture was prohibited the slicing and def function on my task (just looping)

```
first_length = 8
second_length = 5
first_word = 'institut'
second_word = 'utara'

result = []
if first_length <= second_length :
    for i in range(1,first_length + 1):
        if first_word[-i:] == second_word[:i]:
            result = first_word[-i:]
else:
    for i in range(1,second_length + 1):
        if first_word[-i:] == second_word[:i]:
            result = first_word[-i:]

print(result)
```

thank you  a lot:))

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Comments like "please help me" only detract from the question.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code the lengths. Use `first_length = len(first_word)`

Comment: @Barmar i see, but the length not my problem

Comment: I never said it was, that was just general coding advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the slice assignments with the `all()` function and a generator loop.

```
        if first_word[-i:] == second_word[:i]:
```

can be rewritten as

```
if all(first_word[-i + x] == second_word[x] for x in range(i))
```

You can also use a `for` loop, but it gets more complicated.

```
for x in range(i):
    if first_word[-i + x] != second_word[x]:
        break
else:
    result = first_word[-i:]
```

The `else:` clause of a `for` or `while` loop is executed if the loop ends normally instead of due to a `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this interpretation of the question is correct.

Looks like the challenge is to determine if a sequence of characters in *second_word* occurs in *first_word*. That sequence can be any length >= 2.

If that's correct then this seems to work. Of course it's not the right way to do it the question clearly states that slicing is not permitted.

```
first = 'institut'
second = 'utara'
minseq = 2
result = []

for k in range(len(second)):
    for i in range(k+minseq, len(second)+1):
        if (w := ''.join(second[j] for j in range(k, i))) in first:
            result.append(w)

print(result)
```

**Note:**

This code looks for **all** possible patterns - i.e., doesn't stop if a single pattern is observed. That's easily changed if required.

**Output:**

```
['ut']
```